# Locking a file in robotframework

Tags: python, multithreading, robotframework

I am using robotframework. I am using pabot to run test suites in parallel.

While running I need to make sure that a file is accessible by one process at a time and other should wait for the process to release that file.

I understand that it could be done through multithreading in python. I am newbie to python. I need help to solve this issue.

Comment: When you say the file should be "accessible", how do you define "accessible"? Are you writing to the file? Reading from it? Both? Are you deleting and recreating it?

Comment: I just need to read from file but it should be read by a process only. If one process is reading it other should not be able to read from it.

Comment: what platform does this need to work on, or does it need to be cross-platform?

Comment: Currently looking for windows but cross-platform would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to robot to handle file locking. There's also no built-in cross-platform mechanism for file locking. However, there are external packages that can do file locking. For example, the [lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile) package looks like a good candidate.

What I recommend is to create a custom keyword in python that does the reading after acquiring the lock. It might look something like this if you're using the lockfile package:

```
# lock_keywords.py
from lockfile import LockFile

def read_file_with_locking(filename):
    lock = LockFile(filename)
    with lock:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
    return data
```

You would then use it in a test like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | lock_keywords.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Read a file, with locking
| | ${data}= | Read file with locking | /tmp/junk.txt
| | log | data: ${data}
```

I only tested this on a Mac, by opening an interactive python shell and acquiring a lock on the file using the lockfile library, and then running the test in a different window. The test paused until I manually released the lock in the interactive session, at which point it was able to acquire the lock and read the file.

Comment: Thanks for quick response:) will try solution provided by you. Thanks again

Comment: I tried above code. It works fine the way you tested it. But when I tried to run this for multiple test suite using pabot it's failing. Both processes gets lock same time. Is it because pabot creates two separate processes to run the suite?

Comment: Also noticed that in robotframework, when Read file with locking executes lock get released due to this i am getting above problem. When I execute Read file with locking in python shell this doesn't happen.

Comment: @sachin: sorry it didn't work for you. I don't currently have a way to test it on a windows machine.

Comment: @Bryan.. just one question.. is it possible to lock file in a keyword and release lock in other keyword. That can solve my problem :)

Comment: @Sachin: yes, it is possible.